# how do you build the url in R

Tags: r, rcurl

There are reports on sitescope server that I would to be able to use RCurl package to pull the data and parse it to do some automation.

this is the url:

"http://server1.sitescope1.hosting.net:8888/SiteScope/accounts/login59/htdocs/Reports-1725002550/Report-01_05-01_25_2015.txt"

this part (01_25_2015) easy, it is date that report runs, I can build it like this:

```
 d<-format(Sys.time(),"%m_%d_%Y")
```

The problem is with this:

```
01_05
```

01 is the hour that report is configured to run, but depending on how long does it take (in this case, report started at 01 and completed 05). However, 05 could have been any number from 01 to 60, realistically maybe from 01 to 10.

When I build the url:

I can use RCurl package to pull the url, assuming the url is valid with this:

```
x<-getURL(url, userpwd="userid:password", connecttimeout=60)
```

My question is this:

Assuming that I know the hour of the report that supposed to run, is there a way to determine the minute section of the url without making multiple url calls? OR how would you build the url before calling using RCurl?

as suggested by Scott:

I have done this:

```
url <- "http://server1.sitescope1.hosting.net:8888/SiteScope/accounts/login59/htdocs/Reports-1725002550/"

filenames <- getURL(url, dirlistonly=TRUE)
```

this will get me an html output like this:

```
 "<HTML>\r\n<HEAD>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Expires\" content=\"0\"/>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Pragma\" content=\"no-cache\"/>\n\r\n<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Content-Type\" CONTENT=\"text/html;CHARSET=Cp1252\"/>\r\n\r\n<TITLE>file</TITLE>\r\n<LINK REL=\"stylesheet\" TYPE=\"text/css\" HREF=\"/SiteScope/htdocs/artwork/sitescopeUI.css\"/>\r\n</HEAD>\n\r\n<BODY BGCOLOR=\"#ffffff\" LINK=#1155bb ALINK=#1155bb VLINK=#1155bb>\n\r\n<H2></H2><p><p>\r\n<A HREF=/SiteScope/accounts/login59/htdocs/Reports-1725002550/latest.html><B>Most Recent Report</B></A>\r\n<P><CENTER>\n<A NAME=uptimeSummary> </A>\n<TABLE WIDTH=\"100%\" BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=0>\n <CAPTION><B>Report Summary</B></CAPTION>\r\n <TR BGCOLOR=\"#88AA99\"><TH>&nbsp;</TH><TH COLSPAN=2>WTAD::Linux: Total CPU Percent Utilization on dc2prwtag1</TH><TH COLSPAN=2>WTAD::Linux: Total CPU Percent Utilization on dc2prwtag10</TH><TH COLSPAN=2>WTAD::Linux: Total CPU Percent Utilization on dc2prwtag11</TH><TH COLSPAN=2>WTAD::Linux: Total CPU Percent Utilization on dc2prwtag12</TH><TH COLSPAN=2>WTAD::Linux: Total CPU Percent Utilization on dc2prwtag13</TH><TH COLSPAN=2>WTAD::Linux: Total CPU Percent Utilization on dc2prwtag14</TH><TH COLSPAN=2>WTAD::Linux: Total CPU Percent Utilization on dc2prwtag15</TH><TH COLSPAN=2>WTAD::Linux: Total CPU Percent Utilization on dc2prwtag16</TH><TH COLSPAN=2>WTAD::Linux: Total CPU Percent Utilization on dc2prwtag2</TH><TH COLSPAN=2>WTAD::Linux: Total CPU Percent Utilization on server1</TH><TH COLSPAN=2>WTAD::Linux: Total CPU Percent Utilization on dc2prwtag4</TH><TH COLSPAN=2>WTAD::Linux: Total CPU Percent Utilization on server2</TH><TH COLSPAN=2>WTAD::Linux: Total CPU Percent Utilization on dc2prwtag6</TH><TH COLSPAN=2>WTAD::Linux: Total CPU Percent Utilization on server3</TH><TH COLSPAN=2>WTAD::Linux: Total CPU Percent Utilization on dc2prwtag8</TH><TH COLSPAN=2>WTAD::Linux: Total CPU Percent Utilization on server9</TH><TH COLSPAN=2>WTAD::Linux: Total CPU Percent Utilization on dc2prwtag17</TH><TH COLSPAN=2>WTAD::Linux: Total CPU Percent Utilization on server10</TH></TR>\r\n <TR BGCOLOR=\"#DDDDDD\"><TD><B>Information For</B></TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>avg</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>peak</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>avg</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>peak</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>avg</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>peak</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>avg</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>peak</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>avg</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>peak</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>avg</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>peak</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>avg</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>peak</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>avg</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>peak</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>avg</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>peak</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>avg</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>peak</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>avg</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>peak</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>avg</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>peak</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>avg</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>peak</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>avg</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>peak</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>avg</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>peak</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>avg</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>peak</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>avg</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>peak</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>avg</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT>peak</TD></TR>\r\n <TR BGCOLOR=\"#DDDDDD\"><TD><A HREF=/SiteScope/accounts/login59/htdocs/Reports-1725002550/Report-15_33-01_25_2015.html>3:33 PM 1/18/15 - 3:33 PM 1/25/15</A> (<A HREF=/SiteScope/accounts/login59/htdocs/Reports-1725002550/Report-15_33-01_25_2015.txt>text</A>)</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">3.67%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">28%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">2.85%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">10%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">1.65%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">18%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">4.54%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">14%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">4.12%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">15%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">4.42%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">18%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">0%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">2%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">0.72%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">6%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">4.26%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">30%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">3.42%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">16%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">3.4%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">16%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">1.58%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">7%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">0.46%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">7%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">0.4%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">2%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">1.49%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">11%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">2.25%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">8%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">0%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">0%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">0.49%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">4%</TD></TR>\r\n <TR BGCOLOR=\"#DDDDDD\"><TD><A HREF=/SiteScope/accounts/login59/htdocs/Reports-1725002550/Report-01_05-01_25_2015.html>1:05 AM 1/18/15 - 1:05 AM 1/25/15</A> (<A HREF=/SiteScope/accounts/login59/htdocs/Reports-1725002550/Report-01_05-01_25_2015.txt>text</A>)</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">3.68%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">28%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">2.75%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">10%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">1.6%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">18%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">4.41%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">14%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">4.11%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">15%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">4.39%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">18%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">0%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">2%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">0.72%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">6%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">4.25%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">30%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">3.43%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">16%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">3.39%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">16%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">1.58%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">7%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">0.46%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">7%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">0.4%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">2%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">1.49%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">11%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">2.17%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">8%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">0%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">0%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">0.55%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">4%</TD></TR>\r\n <TR BGCOLOR=\"#DDDDDD\"><TD><A HREF=/SiteScope/accounts/login59/htdocs/Reports-1725002550/Report-11_26-01_20_2015.html>11:26 AM 1/13/15 - 11:26 AM 1/20/15</A> (<A HREF=/SiteScope/accounts/login59/htdocs/Reports-1725002550/Report-11_26-01_20_2015.txt>text</A>)</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">3.83%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">27%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">2.74%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">15%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">1.51%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">6%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">4.64%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">20%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">4.32%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">21%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">4.84%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">20%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">0%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">1%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">0.72%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">7%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">4.39%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">27%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">3.49%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">16%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">3.45%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">16%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">1.65%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">7%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">0.51%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">6%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">0.42%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">6%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">1.55%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">7%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">2.11%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">8%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">0%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">1%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">0.61%</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\">4%</TD></TR>\r\n</TABLE></CENTER>\r\n<P><FORM ACTION=\"/SiteScope/cgi/go.exe/SiteScope\" method=\"POST\">\n<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"page\" value=\"adhocReport\"/>\n<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"queryID\" value=\"1725002550\"/>\n<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"htmlFile\" value=\"yes\"/>\n<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"account\" value=\"login59\"/>\n<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"isFlipperContext\" value=\"false\"/>\n<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"isSwingContext\" value=\"true\"/>\n<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"locale\" value=\"en_US\"/>\n<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"useOldLinks\" value=\"false\"/>\n<input class=\"button\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Generate\" onclick=\"this.disabled=true; this.value= 'Generating. Wait..'; document.forms[0].submit();\" />\n</FORM>\nManagement Report Now - this will immediately generate and save this report, using the most current data\n (<B>Note: </B>This may take a few moments, depending on the speed of the SiteScope machine, the number of monitors and the time period of the report)\n</BODY></HTML>\r\n"
```

as you can see there are HREF sections: HREF=/SiteScope/accounts/login59/htdocs/Reports-1725002550/Report-15_33-01_25_2015.txt>

I need to be able to  build the url from the latest HREF.

Comment: Is there some way you can get a list of all the files (and thus the hour/minute information) for a specific day?

Comment: @ScottWilson, I can only get the hour of the report and day. Minute section is dynamically inserted when the report completes.

Comment: Right, but I'm asking if you can do a directory listing on the site?  (It's local to you, so I can't test it myself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could do a directory listing you could use

```
url <- "http://server1.sitescope1.hosting.net:8888/SiteScope/accounts/login59/htdocs/Reports-1725002550/"

filenames <- getURL(url, dirlistonly=TRUE)
```

and then parse filenames to get the files you want (then retrieve those).  Something like this, using your example of "Report-01_05-01_25_2015.txt" (where the 05 was uncertain).

```
flist <-unlist(strsplit(filenames, "\n"))
l <- grep("Report-01_..-01_25_2015.txt", flist,value=TRUE)
```

Then just grab `l[length(l)]` and that's your last one.

Comment: from you recommendation, I can get a html output where there are href links where I need to pull the latest href and build the url, any ideas?

Comment: Scan the list for the date and time you're looking for, build a list of files that match, sort it, and pull the last entry from this list.  Then add this on to `url` using paste and you have your file's url.

Comment: any ideas how I could grep lines that start with HREF end with >?

Comment: Updated with an example of how to grep.